# Writing a sql query that captures the 2022 YTD data and compare to same period from 2021.. ex"Jan 1 to Jun 10 2022" vs "Jan 1 to Jun 10 2021"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SUM(case when TO_DATE(WO.W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') between (sysdate -365) and sysdate then PM.M_GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_SVG else 0 end) as CURRENT_KWH_12,

SUM(case when TO_DATE(WO.W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') between sysdate -730 and (sysdate -365) then PM.M_GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_SVG else 0 end) as PREVIOUS_LAST_KWH_12,

SUM(case when TO_DATE(WO.W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') between (sysdate -365) and sysdate then PM.M_GROSS_ANNUAL_THERM_SVG else 0 end) as CURRENT_THERMS_12,

sum(case when TO_DATE(WO.W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') between sysdate -730 and (sysdate -365) then PM.M_GROSS_ANNUAL_THERM_SVG else 0 end) as PREVIOUS_LAST_THERMS_12,
```

...  i think the "current" data needs to be W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE >= 2022-01-01

and the [2:09 PM] Siegel, James R

and the "previous" data needs to be W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE between 2021-01-01 and today's date -365 days

but i just need help writing it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to compare values between the start of this year until now to between the start of last year and the same date as now last year:

```sql
SUM(
  CASE
  WHEN WO.W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')
                                           AND SYSDATE
  THEN PM.M_GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_SVG
  END
) AS CURRENT_KWH,
SUM(
  CASE
  WHEN WO.W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -12)
                                           AND ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
  THEN PM.M_GROSS_ANNUAL_KWH_SVG
  END
) as PREVIOUS_KWH
```

Comment: how would I get sql to return the number of projects done between certain dates?

sum(case when TO_DATE(W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') between TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and sysdate then PROJ_ID else 0 end) as P_YTD_2022_CNT,

sum(case when TO_DATE(W_MEASURE_CLAIMS_SAVING_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') between TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and (sysdate -365) then PROJ_ID else 0 end) as p_YTD_2021_CNT ,--get distinct project id count

Comment: @DanielleHanlon Use `COUNT` rather than `SUM` and use `ELSE NULL` rather than `0`. If you want to get the distinct count then use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...`.